# Create a user profile page dynamically - httphandler? profile provider?

Tags: dynamic-data, httphandler, profile, provider

I want to dynamically create a user profile page with user info displayed (name, address, uploaded content, etc.). I've looked at many tutorials online related to this, but am not sure which way is best. I am using ASP.NET Membership provider for user data. Should I use HTTPHandler and create the ashx file? or just use the Request.QueryString method directly in my code behind? And I'm not sure where ASP.NET Profile provider fits into all this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Forms Authentication in my site.   As an example, to set the Welcome to the site label, i have

```
this.lblUserName.Text = "Welcome " + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name:
```

If you added more personal information to the Userdata property of the forms ticket, you could show that personalized information similarly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Machine: thanks for your reply. My question is more about how to create that page dynamically. For example, how do I go about displaying www.mysite.com/joanne for user joanne?